# plot from csv number of male/female

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I need to plot the total number of male/female persons in pandas. I have a .csv with a column for the names and a true/false-column for female/male.

```
                name    female
0   Mildner, Reinhard   False
1   Wesely, Peter   False
... ... ...
182 Patsch, Sylvia M.   True
183 Gergely, Stefan M.  False
```

How can I plot this data in pandas, so that I get a barplot with two bars, one representing the total number of males, one the total number of females?

Comment: Is pandas necessary? What have you tried so far? Sounds like you are pretty new to pandas. Maybe try excel?

Comment: just plot the values of column "female" (which will be true and false). then rename the x axis labels. i suggest you look into matplotlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with rename index values and then [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
s = df['female'].value_counts().rename({True:'Female',False:'Male'})

s.plot.bar(colors=['r','b'])
```

Answer (score 0):

! would save them into a tuple, name and a `bool` which is for an example `True` if it's a man and `False` if it's a woman. Then you can check if the `bool` is `True` in a for loop and count them. Then you have the number if men there is in the list. Then you can take that number and subtract them of the total elements in the array where you have the persons.